# In react native, How to make function in Component to global?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, global-functions

Main javascript soure code like this,

```
import React from 'react'
import LoadingScreen from './components/LoadingScreen'

import './js/Login'
import './js/XHR'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      load: false,
    }
  }

  XHRget = async parameter => {
    this.setState({ load: true });

    await XHR.send(parameter)
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({ load: false });
        console.log(result);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <LoginScreen />
        <LoadingScreen load={this.state.load}></LoadingScreen>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

I create `XHRget()` in **App.js** for control the 'LoadingScreen' component.

**XHR.js** has two functions. 1) create and return XMLHttpRequest funciton called `create()` and 2) get data from server function called `send()`.

And now, I want call the function `XHRget()` from `login()` in **Login.js** but, I don't know how to call.

How can I call the function `XHRget()` from another js file?

Comment: Just write all common service / function into one class in one file, and export it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, if I write all common services & functions in "common.js", how can I change the 'App' component's state...? As I know, call the 'this.setState()' function of 'App' is only in App component class, doesn't it...? Is there a way to call the App's setState function from another function in 'common.js'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new file with what ever name you like and put the function inside then export it.

ex.

```
export const XHRget = async (parent,parameter) =>
{
   parent.setState({load: true});
   await XHR.send(parameter)
         .then(result => {
             parent.setState({load: false});
             console.log(result);
             });
}
```

Remember to pass in `this` when calling it

Comment: Ok, Thanks! I'll try it!